# React - how to get array from store before first render and use it as dataset for ChartJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, chart.js, react-chartjs

I've implemented my own method to handle click event at chart label (React ChartJS 2 library) and it's for filtering data. I have a little problem becouse I'm storing state of filters for specific user so at first, when I'm initializing view with that chart I have to get array with actual filters. The problem is that even when I'm getting this array, I can't use it in my method becouse it's always undefined. What is important - every time I'm adding new filter, i'm also sending array of filters to store. I'm pretty new in React so Your advices will be really welcome.

This is part of my code (mayby componentDidMount is not good choice?):

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        itemsArray: []
    };
}

componentDidMount(): void {
    // Overview doughnut chart filtering
    AppStore.instance.select(selectQuickQueryParams).pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)).subscribe((quickQueryParam: QueryParamListState) => {
        this.setState({itemsArray: quickQueryParam.entities['Connection:NOT IN:connectionType:QuickFiltersComponent'] ? quickQueryParam.entities['Connection:NOT IN:connectionType:QuickFiltersComponent'].value : []})
    });

    const originalDoughnutLegendBehavior = Chart.defaults.doughnut.legend.onClick;
        Chart.defaults.doughnut.legend.onClick = function (e, legendItem) {
            if (!legendItem.hidden) {
                if (!this.state.itemsArray.includes(legendItem.text)) {
                    this.state.itemsArray.push(legendItem.text);
                }
                const query = new QueryParam(EQueryEntity.Connection, 'connectionType', this.itemsArray, EQueryOperator.NotIn, 'QuickFiltersComponent');
                AppStore.instance.dispatch(new AddQuickQueryParamsAction([query]));
                AppStore.instance.dispatch(new GetUpdateQuickFilters(true));
            } else {
                if (this.state.itemsArray.length > 1) {
                    for (let i = this.state.itemsArray.length; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (this.state.itemsArray[i] === legendItem.text) {
                            this.state.itemsArray.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    const query = new QueryParam(EQueryEntity.Connection, 'connectionType', this.itemsArray, EQueryOperator.NotIn, 'QuickFiltersComponent');
                    AppStore.instance.dispatch(new AddQuickQueryParamsAction([query]));
                    AppStore.instance.dispatch(new GetUpdateQuickFilters(true));
                } else {
                    AppStore.instance.dispatch(new ClearQuickQueryParamsAction());
                }
            }
            originalDoughnutLegendBehavior.call(this, e, legendItem);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `componentDidMount` method only to fetch the list and then in `componentDidUpdate` method you can update that list with the filter and it will re-render your component with the latest data.

Comment: You mean componentDidUpdate in both cases?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunatly it didn't help. I'm still getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemsArray' of undefined' when I want to click on label..

Comment: I am assuming you were using `this.state.itemsArray` or `const {itemsArray} = this.state;`. If still you have issues let me know I will write an example for you.

Comment: As You can see in my code, i'm using this.state.itemsArray and in this case I'm getting error all the time I click on chart label